# How to join three database tables in sql

Tags: sql, database, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I have these three database tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bus_info` (
  `bus_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bus_no` varchar(20) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO `bus_info` (`bus_id`, `bus_no`) VALUES
(1, 'Mh10 BD 5209');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `route_info` (
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `route_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(200) NOT NULL
)


INSERT INTO `route_info` (`route_id`, `route_name`, `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES
(1, 'Sangli Stand', '16.852903', '74.562999'),
(2, 'Maruti Chowk', '16.858100', '74.562460'),
(3, 'Ganpati Mandir', '16.862211', '74.559501'),
(4, 'College Corner ', '16.862854', '74.576579'),
(5, 'Ram Mandir ', '16.856413', '74.574738'),
(6, 'D mart', '16.845782', '74.576866'),
(7, 'Vishrambag sangli', '16.846022', '74.602854'),
(8, 'Bharat Mill', '16.865029', '74.607000'),
(9, 'Bharti hospital', '16.840008', '74.618400'),
(10, 'SBGI', '16.835329', '74.624400');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `route_detail` (
  `rd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bus_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO `route_detail` (`rd_id`, `bus_id`, `route_id`)
    VALUES (1, 1, 1),
           (2, 1, 2);
```

I am assigning a particular route for a single bus there may have multiple routes for single bus then i need a query for selecting a route for selected bus

for ex:

from database in route_detail table there are assigned two route for same bus then I need columns from above three tables are

**bus_id,bus_no, route_id,latitude,longitude**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it.....

```
SELECT 
    bus_info.bus_no, route_detail.route_id, route_info.latitude, 
    route_info.longitude 
FROM 
    (bus_info 
INNER JOIN 
    route_detail ON bus_info.bus_id = route_detail.bus_id) 
INNER JOIN 
    route_info ON route_detail.route_id = route_info.route_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact syntax will depend on the database you are using.  To do this in Oracle I would expect to write a query like this;

```
select a.bus_id, a.bus_no, c.route_id, c.latitude, c.longitude
from
bus_info a join
route_detail b on a.bus_id = b.bus_id
route_info c on b.route_id = c.route_id
where {alias.column_name} {operator} {operand};
```

You need one join statement for each table you wish to join.
Each join works by finding matching keys on the two tables to be joined.
Use table aliases (a, b, c etc.) to keep the query succinct.
The result of all your joins is one big table which you can query from in the normal way.
I can't tell from your question exactly what you want to know about each bus, so inner or outer joins may be better for you.  By default an inner join is done, which means only rows matching all query criteria will be included.  Broadly speaking an outer join brings back more stuff.